# ¿Por qué no me inserta el registro en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estoy intentando insertar un usuario si no existe su correo en la base de datos. Hasta el momento sí me válida si existe un correo en la base de datos pero si no existe el correo en la base de datos, no se insertan los datos y no me aparece ningún error de código ni nada, ¿Cuál es el problema?

Les dejo el código que estoy utilizando a continuación:

```
    include 'conexion.php';



    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
       $nombre = $_POST["user"];
       $apellido = $_POST["apelli"];
       $clave = $_POST["clave"];
       $correo = $_POST["email"];
       $sexo = $_POST["sex"];
       introducir el código aquí
       //Procederemos a hacer una consulta que buscara el correo del usuario
       $buscarCorreo = "SELECT * from personas WHERE correo = '$correo'";

       //Realizamos la consulta y anadimos $connection, ya que es la variable que creamos en nuestro archivo connection.php
       $resultado = $conn->query($buscarCorreo);


       //Usaremos la funcion mysqli_num_rows en la consulta $resultado,
       //esta funcion nos regresa el numero de filas en el resultado
       $contador = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

       //SI SI EXISTE una fila, quiere decir QUE SI ESTA EL CORREO EN LA BASE DE DATOS

       $errorcorreo = "Correo invalido jaja";
             if($contador == 1) {
                echo $errorcorreo; 
             } else {
               $sql = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido, correo) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo')");
               mysqli_close($conn);
             }

   }
 ?>
```

Comment: He notado que aún no has leído el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
de Stack Overflow en Español. mejora su pregunta y mira cómo hacerlo en este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos.

Comment: @Mauricio en realidad no es una pregunta mas bien es que tenia un problema en el código y busque en otras fuentes,y lo resolvi.

Comment: deberías entonces actualizar tu pregunta con la descripción del problema que tuviste _y ayudaría a la comunidad_ si compartes la fuente de donde obtuviste la solución. Revisa el recorrido para entender como formular una pregunta en este sitio, nuestro sitio.

Comment: ¿Cuál es (era) la pregunta aquí?

Comment: @Shaz Ninguna.Solo era decir cual era el problema que había resuelto.

Comment: ¿Cuál era el problema entonces?

Comment: @Shaz Faltaba implementar la sentencia "MySqli_query"para hacer  un "INSERT INTO"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $nombre = $_POST["user"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apelli"];
    $clave = $_POST["clave"];
    $correo = $_POST["email"];
    $sexo = $_POST["sex"];    
    //Procederemos a hacer una consulta que buscara el correo del usuario
    $buscarCorreo = "SELECT * from personas WHERE correo = '$correo'";    
    //Realizamos la consulta y anadimos $connection, ya que es la variable que creamos en nuestro archivo connection.php
    $resultado = $conn->query($buscarCorreo);
    //Usaremos la funcion mysqli_num_rows en la consulta $resultado,
    //esta funcion nos regresa el numero de filas en el resultado
    $contador = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);    
    //SI SI EXISTE una fila, quiere decir QUE SI ESTA EL CORREO EN LA BASE DE DATOS    
    $errorcorreo = "Correo invalido jaja";
    if($contador == 1) {        
        echo $errorcorreo;
        return false;        
    } else {
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO personas (nombre, apellido, correo) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo')");        
        mysqli_close($conn);        
    }
}
?>
```

El problema estaba en que no había usado **MySQL_query** para hacer el guardado en la base de datos.